# getting error while setting a global variable during recurssion in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

so i have implemented a timer in my ember code, which works fine, but while running test it fails i get this error saying

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object: <front@component:qwtery/my-comp::ember629>.timer = 9
```

note that this happens only when i run the tests

and here is my code

```
didReceiveAttrs(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('timerStop', false);
    this.set('anotherTimer', 0);
    this.set('timer', null);
    var timeLimit = this.get('question.time_limit');
    if(timeLimit > 0)
    {
      this.set('timerEnabled', true);
      this.timerFunc(timeLimit,0);
    }
  },

timerFunc: function(count, val) {
    if (count >= 0 && !this.get('timerStop')) {
      this.set('timer', count);
      this.set('anothertimer', val);

      var a = setTimeout(() => {
        return this.timerFunc(count-1, val+1);
      }, 1000)
    }
    else {
      code to show message that timer has stopped
    }
  }
```

So if this is not the right way to implement a timer,
why do i get the message "calling set on destroyed object:" only while running the test and not while i try it out manually

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear your timers while component is about to destroy. You can use `willDestroyElement` hook.
See: [Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_detaching-and-tearing-down-component-elements-with-willdestroyelement)

Alternatively, you can check `if (this.get('isDestroyed') )` to see whether the component destroyed or not. [Api Doc](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.9/classes/CoreObject/properties/isDestroyed?anchor=isDestroyed). This can be a quick win, but I don't think this is the correct way. Clearing the timers is the correct way.

Secondly, do not use `setTimeout`. Instead use `later`. See: [Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/run-loop/)

Comment: The code i included is the component code, the timer works fine in real life, basically i want the user to perform some action only for a particular period, my only problem is i  cant test it properly as it throws me the error "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object: <front@component:qwtery/my-comp::ember629>.timer = 9" when i run the ember tests (ie ember t -s)

Comment: basically i m using recursion for the timer, when the function "timerFunc" called for the first time it works fine, but during the second call for this line "this.set('timer', count);" it throws an error "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object: <front@component:qwtery/my-comp::ember629>.timer = 9"  only wile running the tests

Comment: Ok, that's normal. Your test code renders the component then tests your assertions and then disposes it. But since you don't clear your timer, you are facing this issue. Because timer tries to reach disposed component. How do you test this code? How do you make the test wait for the timers to stop?